# Error: cannot convert parameters from 'int [10]' to 'int'

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

This is a fairly simple program for the implementation of Stack. But there is a problem with the declaration of the `push()`, `pop()` and `display()` functions. The error statements are as follows. Please help me figure out the problem.

Error:

```
error C2664: 'push' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [10]' to 'int'
error C2664: 'pop' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [10]' to 'int'
error C2664: 'display' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int [10]' to 'int'
```

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#define STACKSIZE 10
using namespace std;
void push(int,int,int);
void pop(int,int);
void display(int,int);
int main()
{
    int stack[STACKSIZE],n,data,stackptr=-1;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"1. Push\n2. Pop\n3. Display\n4. Exit\n";
        cin>>n;
        switch(n)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"\nEnter a data to push: ";
            cin>>data;
            push(stack,stackptr,data);
            break;
        case 2:
            pop(stack, stackptr);
            break;
        case 3:
            display(stack, stackptr);
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(1);
            break;
        default:
                cout<<"\nEnter correct choice...\n\n";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void display(int stack[STACKSIZE], int &stackptr)
{
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0;i<stackptr;i++)
        cout<<stack[i]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n\n";
}
void push(int stack[STACKSIZE],int &stackptr, int data)
{
    if(stackptr == STACKSIZE - 1)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nStack full\n\n";
        return ;
    }
    stackptr++;
    stack[stackptr] = data;
}
void pop(int stack[STACKSIZE], int &stackptr)
{
    if(stackptr == 0)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nStack Empty\n\n";
        return ;
    }
    stackptr = stackptr-1;
}
```

Comment: Make an SSCCE and you'll probably discover the error for yourself.

Comment: I did try with various other declarations like void push(int*,int,int) or void push(int[],int,int), etc, but none worked correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer given by Gangadhar and Jansel is incomplete. You are passing values by reference so this is not enough:

```
void push(int stack[size],int,int);
```

This is what you need:

```
void push(int[],int&,int);
void pop(int[],int&);
void display(int[],int&);
```

Comment: Thanks man!! your were the first to figure out.. so I'll select your answer as the best..

Answer (score 4):

Your function's declarations are wrong. for example:

```
void push(int, int, int);
//        ^^^ int
```

Just correct it

```
void push(int stack[], int&, int);
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^ should be int[]
```

Comment: The definition has a reference.

Comment: Didn't work. It says `more than one instance of overloaded function "push" matches the argument list`
`more than one instance of overloaded function "pop" matches the argument list`
`more than one instance of overloaded function "display" matches the argument list`

Comment: @VISHNUVIVEK - The answer is incomplete - check my answer.

Comment: @chris You means second argument in `push()` function na? it should be like `int&`

Comment: @Acme No now it is completed after Chris's comment. I notice one more mistake.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Not its still not - his answer still does not solve the errors for pop and display.

Comment: @Acme **No** because same mistakes in all function's declarations, He given an example with `push()`

Comment: @VISHNUVIVEK This mistake is because your arguments in definition and in declaration are different, so compiler assumes you are overloading functions.

Comment: chris thanks for  pointing out reference, GrijeshChauhan thank you for correcting answer. i did not notice reference. acme corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You were ***making mistake in function declaration***. This is the correct way.

```
void push(int[],int&,int);
void pop(int[],int&);
void display(int[],int&);
```

Answer (score 2):

These error are self explanatory `push`,`pop` and `display` functions prototypes receives 3 `int` parameters, and you are trying to pass `int[]` by first first parameter, so, change your functions prototype to receive `int[]` of it first  parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function prototype for push/pop at the start that declares an int not an array.

```
void push(int, int, int);
```

This is the version the compiler uses to check your call against. Rewrite these prototypes to have the function signature as the functions themselves.